# Line Breaking and Tab Spacing in g.drawString in Java SE

Tags: java, drawstring

I got the coding separately for these Line breaking & Tab Spacing.

Line Spacing:

```
private void drawString(Graphics g, String text, int x, int y) {
    for (String line : text.split("\n")) {
        g.drawString(line, x, y += g.getFontMetrics().getHeight());
    }
}
```

Tab Spacing:

```
private void drawtabString(Graphics g, String text, int x, int y) {
    for (String line : text.split("\t")) {
        g.drawString(line, x += g.getFontMetrics().getHeight(), y);
    }
}
```

How can I combine this codes?

Where I want the out put of `g.drawString("Line 1\t:Words\t\nLine 2\t:\tWords", x, y);` :
Like;

```
Line 1 [tab space]: [tabspace] Words
Line 2 [tab space]: [tabspace] Words
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private void drawString(Graphics g, String text, int x, int y) {
    for (String line : text.split("\n")) {
        drawtabString(g, line, x, y += g.getFontMetrics().getHeight());
    }
}
```

Note: embedding the modification of the `y` variable inside the method call makes it confusing. I would separate it into 2 instructions to make the code more obvious:

```
drawtabString(g, line, x, y);
y += g.getFontMetrics().getHeight();
```

PS: are you sure you don't want to simply use a JTextArea?